# How can I change the color/style of ToolBarItem's when the toolbar changes from translucent to opaque in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

[image]

Basically, I need a way to detect when the toolbar has gone from being transparent to opaque. At that point, I would like to remove the grey background from all of the items in the toolbar and change the text color to black. However, I have searched for a few days now, and I don't see any way that this can be detected.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this effect is to implement the toolbar/header yourself as an overlay over the scrolled content. This way, the header shares the same coordinate space as the content, so a `GeometryReader` can be used to detect when the content has been scrolled.

- In the scrolled state, you can set a `Material` background behind the header and change the appearance of the icons.
- Use `Material.bar` to match the style of system toolbars.
- Another `GeometryReader` can be used to find the height of the safe area insets at the top of the screen, so that this space can be allowed for.

Something like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    let loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

    @Namespace private var namespace

    private func icon(systemName: String, withFilledBackground: Bool) -> some View {
        Image(systemName: systemName)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .padding(8)
            .foregroundColor(withFilledBackground ? .white : .black)
            .frame(width: 34, height: 34)
            .background {
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(withFilledBackground ? .gray : .clear)
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 5)
            .padding(.horizontal, 8)
    }

    private func header(title: String, withFilledBackgrounds: Bool) -> some View {
        Text(title)
            .accessibilityHeading(.h1)
            .foregroundColor(withFilledBackgrounds ? .white : .black)
            .padding(.vertical, 4)
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .background {
                Capsule()
                    .foregroundColor(withFilledBackgrounds ? .gray : .clear)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 44)
            .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                icon(systemName: "chevron.left", withFilledBackground: withFilledBackgrounds)
                    .accessibilityLabel("Back")
                    .accessibilityAddTraits(.isButton)
                    .onTapGesture { print("back") }
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
                HStack {
                    icon(systemName: "trash", withFilledBackground: withFilledBackgrounds)
                        .accessibilityLabel("Delete")
                        .accessibilityAddTraits(.isButton)
                        .onTapGesture { print("delete") }
                    icon(systemName: "pencil", withFilledBackground: withFilledBackgrounds)
                        .accessibilityLabel("Edit")
                        .accessibilityAddTraits(.isButton)
                        .onTapGesture { print("edit") }
                }
            }
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
            .background {
                if withFilledBackgrounds {
                    Color.clear
                } else {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.bar)
                        .transition(.opacity.animation(.easeInOut))
                }
            }
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { outer in
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    Image(systemName: "tortoise")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(height: 150)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .padding(.top, 44 + outer.safeAreaInsets.top)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                    Text(loremIpsum).font(.title2)
                    Text(loremIpsum)
                    Text(loremIpsum)
                }
                .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        let minY = proxy.frame(in: .named(namespace)).minY
                        header(
                            title: "Living Room",
                            withFilledBackgrounds: minY >= 0
                        )
                        .frame(height: 44 + outer.safeAreaInsets.top)
                        .offset(y: -minY)
                    }
                }
            }
            .coordinateSpace(name: namespace)
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

Answer (score 0):

I do not see that SwiftUI would be able to provide a direct way to detect the change from translucent to opaque in the navigation bar.
Maybe you could instead *infer* it from the scroll position or other state changes.

Use the [`ScrollView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollview) reader to detect the scroll offset.
When the offset passes a certain threshold, assume the navigation bar has changed to opaque.
And update the state that controls the appearance of your [`ToolBarItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toolbaritem)s accordingly.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isToolbarOpaque = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self, value: geometry.frame(in: .named("scrollView")).minY)
                }
                .frame(height: 0)
                // Add your content here
            }
            .coordinateSpace(name: "scrollView")
            .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) { value in
                // Adjust the threshold according to when your navigation bar changes
                isToolbarOpaque = value < -100
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        Image(systemName: "pencil")
                            .foregroundColor(isToolbarOpaque ? .black : .gray)
                    }
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                            .foregroundColor(isToolbarOpaque ? .black : .gray)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Items")
            // Use this to set the initial style of your navigation bar
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}

// Preference key to read the scroll view offset
struct ViewOffsetKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = 0
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value += nextValue()
    }
}
```

A `GeometryReader` within a `ScrollView` detects the vertical scroll offset. The `ViewOffsetKey` is a custom preference key that communicates the offset to the parent view.
The `onPreferenceChange` modifier observes changes to the offset and updates the `isToolbarOpaque` state. The `ToolbarItemGroup` changes the foreground color of the toolbar items based on the `isToolbarOpaque` state.