# How to trigger an action when a view passes under the navigation bar?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm looking to trigger an action at the precise moment when a `Text` view of a `List` begins to pass under the navigation bar.

```
struct DemoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<50, id: \.self) { value in
                    Text(value.formatted())
                        .onDisappear(perform: { debugPrint(value) })
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Demo view")
        }
    }
}
```

This solution is unsuitable for two reasons:

- `onDisappear()`, as its name suggests, is not triggered when the `Text` view begins to disappear below the navigation bar, but when it disappears from the screen altogether.
- `onDisappear` is also triggered when the `Text` view disappears from the screen on the bottom side.

Do you please know a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is curious, SwiftUI is doing a few things that might be surprising, but I have a suggestion that solves the two problems you mention, while possibly leaving you with a problem you hadn't identified to still resolve. In the code below, I'm using GeometryReaders on each Text to stash the Y-coordinate of the top of the view into a dictionary called textTops.

```swift
struct DemoView: View {
    @State private var textTops: [Int: CGFloat] = [:]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<50, id: \.self) { value in
                    let textTop = Int(textTops[value] ?? 0.0)   // dropping fractional part for simplicity
                    Text("\(value): \(textTop)")
                        .overlay {
                            GeometryReader { geo in
                                Color.clear
                                    .onAppear {
                                        textTops[value] = geo.frame(in: .named("navStack")).minY
                                    }
                                    .onChange(of: geo.frame(in: .named("navStack")).minY) {
                                        textTops[value] = geo.frame(in: .named("navStack")).minY
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                        .background(textTop < 200 ? .red : .clear)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Demo view")
        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: "navStack")   // this defines the coordinate space we use in our GeometryReaders
    }
}
```

I'm also displaying this value in each row of the list, so you can understand what's going on.

But here's where you'll see some of the strangeness of SwiftUI. The numbers are a lot bigger than you might expect. This is because the y=0 point is the top of the device, not the boundary where you might think the text is starting to disappear.

But the truth is, the text only really disappears at the top of the device, because when it first "disappears" it is still being rendered under the navigation bar and is contributing to the look of the navigation bar, even though severely blurred. You can just make it out if you squint hard. So disappearance really starts when each row's textTop value reaches zero at the top of the device.

You can confirm this, even in your own example. You might have noticed that you don't get the debugPrint messages until the text goes off the top of the device.

So, to demonstrate the sort of thing you might have to do, I have set the background of the Text to red when it scrolls above an arbitrary threshold (`textTop < 200`). You would want to replace that with a value that accomplishes what you need.

If you don't mind the message appearing only when the Text has gone past the top of the device, then set the condition to `textTop < 0`. Otherwise, you'll have to do a bit more work to figure out, in a context-sensitive way, the threshold value you should use.

Answer (score 0):

When the list is scrolled, the navigation title changes from a large title to a smaller title in a navigation bar. The `List` itself scrolls behind the navigation bar, all the way to the top of the display (safe area insets are ignored).

The idea would be to detect when a list item goes behind the navigation bar. This requires knowing the safe area insets at the top of the display and also the height of the navigation bar.

- The safe area insets at the top of the display can be measured using a `GeometryReader` outside of the `NavigationStack`.
- I couldn't think of a way of measuring the height of the navigation bar, so I was going to suggest defining it as a `ScaledMetric`. This way, it would adapt in accordance with the text size on the device. However, in my tests, it seems that the header always has a fixed height which does not depend on the text size. This height is also fairly uniform across different devices. So it can just be defined as a constant.

All that you then need to know is the relative position of a row inside the list. This can be determined by using another `GeometryReader` in the background of each row. This should examine the position of the row in the coordinate space of the list.

Here is your example with the changes applied:

```swift
struct DemoView: View {

    @Namespace private var theList
    private let navBarHeight: CGFloat = 50

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { outer in
            let topInsets = outer.safeAreaInsets.top
            NavigationStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<50, id: \.self) { value in
                        Text(value.formatted())
                            .background {
                                GeometryReader { proxy in
                                    let minY = proxy.frame(in: .named(theList)).minY
                                    let isUnderNavBar = minY < (navBarHeight + topInsets)
                                    Rectangle()
                                        .fill(isUnderNavBar ? .red : .clear)
                                        .onChange(of: isUnderNavBar) { oldVal, newVal in
                                            if newVal {
                                                debugPrint(value)
                                            }
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
                .coordinateSpace(name: theList)
                .navigationTitle("Demo view")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative approach would be to implement the navigation bar yourself. This way, you could detect when the list goes behind the bar more precisely. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77600861/20386264) for an example.